# Recompile Java built-in class

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I had to modify a built-in class in JavaFX, because a method what I need was private, and I changed it to public. Alright, I found the source code in /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_66/javafx-src.zip, I modified the code, restarted Eclipse, and I can see the modification in Eclipse, when I go to definition of the built-in class, but Eclipse still says for the needed method, that it's not visible. I think the problem is, that I have to recompile the built-in class. How can I do it, I searched a lot on the internet, and I didn't found an answer.

Comment: You might be better off explaining _why_ you need to make a private function public, this is a really bad idea

Comment: There is almost certainly a better way to do whatever you are trying to do. (And using Reflection might be the least worst option)

Comment: You **might** be able to make it work on your machine; but it won't work with any other installed version of Java (and it won't really **be** Java anymore).

Comment: @tddmonkey The Image class of JavaFX has a method called <code>getImpl_source()</code> , which returns the ImputStream of image, and it's private, but I need this, so that's the reason of changing the visibility.

Comment: You don't need to call that method. Find another way to do whatever it is you're trying to do. At some point, you load the image, so just keep a reference to the source of the image when you do so.

Comment: @James_D thanks the idea, I solved the problem by saving the InputStream of the image in a HashMap, associated with the Image.

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer this let me make it very clear that it is a bad practice and this approach is wrong.

But if you really want to have a work around you could get the source code of that class.

Change the name of the class per se and add it to your classpath and use it.
You can make the re-edits in this class file.

Comment: I don't think this will work, because the class references other classes that are private API; so the renamed class will not compile on its own. You'd basically need to rebuild an entire section of the source code. But, as you say, you just shouldn't be doing this at all.

Comment: True that.It is a bad practice.